# Sizing a shape in points in VBA does not equal size in inches

Tags: excel, vba

A weird, annoying problem. Can anyone advise what might be happening?

Using Microsoft Office ProPlus, working in VBA in Excel.

I'm setting the height & width of an drawing object (shape) in an Excel sheet, using in VBA:

```
Isizevalue = CInt(Application.InchesToPoints(Cells(conFirstRow + i - 1, 7).Value)) 'value in a cell
' select the object
 ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array([object selection])).Select
Selection.Width = Isizevalue
Selection.Height = Selection.Width
```

When I check the dimensions in VB, they're the same in points:

`MsgBox Selection.Height = Selection.Width`

Shows TRUE.

But when I look at the properties of the object in the Excel shape attributes, the height & width are different, by a 100th of an inch (e.g., 1.39" vs 1.38"). Sometimes they match, often they don't and they're off by 0.01".

I've tried:

- Turning the lock aspect ratio attribute to true / false
- setting the value of Isizevalue explicitly to 72 -- I get 1" and 0.99" as the two dimensions
- assigning the two values to be equal to the variable Isizevalue individually
- Rounding the values explicitly

Please help. this is making me and my team crazy.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using CInt?

Comment: Hi Norie - Left over testing. Trying to see if I was getting a fractional value when the inches were being converted to points, so was explicitly casting as an integer in case.